# Text overlaps the hint in textArea - cn1

Tags: codenameone

There are 2 textArea in my screen with necessary hint texts. If the last textArea is focused, the keyboard appears but instead of typing in it, if the other textArea is focused, the new text overlaps the text hints. I've tested in the textFields also, but here the hint disppears as soon as it is focused. However it is not the case in textArea. P.S I've tested the app in android devices.

Have a look at the video [here.](https://youtu.be/tfGJdOpP0rM)

**Code:**

```
Label reasonLabel = new Label("Reason* ");

TextArea reasonData = new TextArea();
Container reasonContainer = common.Inputs.inputTextArea(reasonData, "Reason For Ownership Transfer", reasonLabel);

Label remarksLabel = new Label("Remarks ");

TextArea remarksData = new TextArea();
Container remarksContainer = common.Inputs.inputTextArea(remarksData, "Additional Info If Any", remarksLabel);

Container mainContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(phnNoContainer, emailContainer, BoxLayout.encloseY(reasonContainer), BoxLayout.encloseY(remarksContainer));

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, BoxLayout.encloseY(mainContainer, submitButton));
```

**common.Inputs.inputTextArea method:**

```
public static Container inputTextArea(TextArea textArea, String hint, Label textAreaLabel) {
    textArea.setHint(hint);
    textArea.setRows(2);
    textArea.setGrowByContent(false);
    textArea.getHintLabel().setUIID("TextField");

    Container remarksContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(textAreaLabel, textArea);

    return remarksContainer;
}
```

Comment: Please file an issue on this. We need the exact device model and OS version to debug this.

Comment: The device I tested is samsung J7 prime and OS is android version 7.0  Moreover I've tested it in couple of other devices also, all has the same problem.

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2629